# Javascript - can you throw an object in an Error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Is it possible to throw an object using `Error`? In the example below the console shows `undefined`.

```
try {
    throw Error({foo: 'bar'});
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message.foo);
}
```

Comment: you can throw about anything, but that's not how you invoke an Error constructor...

Comment: @dandavis There is no difference between `throw new Error()` and `throw Error()`.

Comment: @K48: I was referring to passing a non-stringify-able object to the constructor...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can throw your own object, and associate an Error instance with it:

```
try {
  // ...
  throw {
    foo: "bar",
    error: new Error()
  };
```

The `throw` statement is not picky, but the `Error()` constructor is. Of course, if you throw something that's not an Error, it's only useful if the catching environment expects it to be whatever you throw.

Having the Error object as part of your custom thrown value is useful because a constructed Error instance has (in supporting browsers, which currently seems to be essentially all of them) an associated stack trace.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone using [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), you can extend the `ErrorConstructor` interface and add your own constructor that accepts an object like this:

```js
class MyError extends Error {
  readonly id: number

  // base constructor only accepts string message as an argument
  // we extend it here to accept an object, allowing us to pass other data
  constructor({ id, name, message }) {
    super(message)
    this.name = name // this property is defined in parent
    this.id = id
  }
}
```

### Usage

```js
function doSomething() {
  if (somethingWentWrong) {
    throw new MyError({
      id: 502,
      name: "throttle_violation",
      message: "Violation of backoff parameter",
    });
  }
}

try {
  doSomething()
} catch (err) {
  if (err instanceof MyError) {
    console.log("error id: " + err.id);
    console.log("error name: " + err.name);
    console.log("error message: " + err.message);
    alert(err.property); // name
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try converting the object to a JSON string and then parsing the error message into a JSON object in the catch statement:

```
try {
    throw Error(JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'}));
} catch (err) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(err.message).foo);
}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` will return `[]` in this case.

Answer (score 6):

you could try with [the `cause` propoty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) of :

> TS has inaccurate value type about it at present, [this is being discussed on the official to resolve it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48098).

```
try {
     throw new Error('Failed in some way', { 
       cause: {foo: 'bar'} 
     });
} catch(e) {
     console.log(e); // Error('Failed in some way')
     console.log(e.cause) // {foo: 'bar'}
}
```

or throw the Error instance with the custom property

```
try {
     const error = new Error('Failed in some way');
     error.foo = 'bar';
     throw error;
   } catch(e) {
     console.log(e); // Error('Failed in some way')
     console.log(e.foo) // 'bar'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` can be a pain and isn't necessary even. I'd suggest creating your own property for the `Error` object, rather than passing the object to the `message` parameter, which only accepts a string.

```
try {
  let error = new Error();
    
  Object.assign(error, { foo: 'bar' });

  throw error;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.foo);
}
```

Comment: This is a good choice for all situations except where you want to use `instanceOf` to change catch behavior based on type of error thrown

Comment: @SandyGifford In that case just use `Object.assign` instead of the spread operator, i.e. `Object.assign(error, { foo: 'bar' })`