# Subsequent Requests produces SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON React Query

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I'm using react query to do a POST request. The request is successful the first time it executes, but keeps producing this error afterwards, even if the page refreshes. It also works if I clear cookies, but only once then the error keeps coming. This is the error message :

```
SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at AxiosClient.js:22:1
at async loginUser (user.api.js:7:1)
at async Mutation.execute (mutation.ts:200:1)
```

I have confirmed that in fact my POST body is not empty or undefined.

Comment: It sounds like your POST request is returning an object instead of JSON, which is causing the error. Try parsing the response from your POST request before returning it to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, this works. It also works if you convert the response to a string then parse it later.

Comment: glad to know, please mark my answer if it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your POST request is returning an object instead of JSON, which is causing the error. Try parsing the response from your POST request before returning it to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

For those who actually want to pass an Object and destructure it later on you cannot use `Error`. Instead you must create your own error that `extends Error`.

There is a full answer on how to implement it available here: [*Javascript - can you throw an object in an Error?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954538/javascript-can-you-throw-an-object-in-an-error).